# Regex if all words contains particular symbols

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a string of emails "test@test.lt; test2@test.lt; test3@test.lt"

how to write simple regex to check if all words contains [@.] at least once in the word?

Comment: What about `a.b@site.co.uk`?

Answer (score 4):

No need for regex:

```
bool allOk = str.Split(';').All(email => email.Count(c => c == '@') == 1);
```

Although this may lead to erronous results (`foo@bar_foo.com` is not a valid email!)

Comment: will work even if you have @;@;@; ...

Comment: @FelicePollano True, but "@ once in each email" is the specification given by the OP. To fully check the emails, he could use split+regex or generic regex.

Comment: Yes, but the OP asked _how to check if all words contains [@.] once in the word_ and I answered the question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think RegEx is necessary but here's the pattern I would use; `\b[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\b`

`\b` is word boundary, then I have the alphanumeric char set. `+` means one or more occurrences of the previous char. So it's saying from a word boundary, it can have 0 or more of any char follow by an @, then again, one or more of any alphnumeric char followed by a word boundary.

Comment: I want to use this expresion in javascript. "\b.*@.*\b" is not correct, because it doesn't validate "test@test.com test".

Comment: Wouldn't .* also match a boundary such as space or ;?

Comment: @Reno it matches "test@test.com" why should it match some random word after the end of the email address? If that's what you want make the trailing word boundary symbol your delimiter instead which appears to be a semi colon. And yes, you may want to replace `.*` with some character set followed by `*` like `[a-zA-Z0-9]*`

Comment: @evanmcdonnal What he meant is that it falsely matches `Hey, how's the g@ing mate?`

Comment: @YoryeNathan alright, well then I'll just have to edit with a more restricted char set. Also changing to pluses since "@foo.com" isn't a valid email address.

Comment: Now it matches a@b - is that valid, with not a single dot?

Comment: @YoryeNathan Well the op's post isn't exactly clear so I don't know. The requirements have been coming out piece wise. If he's looking to match only valid email addresses, then no. `all words contains [@.] at least once` doesn't exactly explain the pattern he wants to match and if it did then there would be no question.

Answer (score 1):

```
[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+?@[_.a-zA-Z0-9-^;]+;?
```

That is some character, followed by `@`, then some non-`;` character, followed by an optional `;`.

Comment: This would match `!@#`, which is corresponding to `123` with a shift, by the way, and isn't an email.

Comment: @YoryeNathan correct, we can refine the .+ part

Comment: Now it doesn't match `a_b@x.y.z` - Not sure if the OP wants to support emails with two dots (example me@hotmail.co.il), but underscore is definitely allowed.

Answer (score 0):

This simple variation on @jsfviky 's answer allows for periods and hyphens in the e-mail address at both the domain level and the local part and also a plus sign for disposable style e-mail addresses:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9-\.\+]{1,}@(?:[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z\.-]{1,}.[a-zA-Z]{1,4}
```

Realistically this is all you will need but valid e-mail addresses may contain any of `!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~` so you might want to vary this depending on usage cases.

Answer (score -2):

If you need an email validator, try out this regexp:

> [a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,}@([a-zA-Z.])?[a-zA-Z]{1,}.[a-zA-Z]{1,4}

Comment: That doesn't look right. It matches `a@.b.c`

Comment: you are right. fixed: [a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,}@([a-zA-Z])?[a-zA-Z]{1,}\.[a-zA-Z]{1,4}

Comment: The `-` character is allowed in emails? I know that `_` is, and maybe even `.`... You could shorten `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` with `\\w`, btw.